# Why I can't install packages du to this OSError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi

I am trying to install packages via a requirements.txt file I have two types, local ones (I created - they are fine) and general ones e.g., fsspec or et-xmlfile, surprisingly it is these that are returning me the following error message which seems to be an OSError:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/96/c2/3dd434b0108730014f1b96fd286040dc3bcb70066346f7e01ec2ac95865f/et_xmlfile-1
.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

in the requirements.txt they are labelled as follows with their version e.g., fsspec==2022.2.0 ; et-xmlfile==1.1.0

I had a look online to see if people had a similar issue, could not find any solution.
I tried to see which ones are the problematical ones and it turned out to be fsspec and et-xmlfile, for instance, another I am installing is cramjam and I don't have any issue with it.
I tried to see if newer versions existed and if it would be a version issue but for these two, I have the latest versions in the requirements.txt file

How can I get rid of this OSError?

Comment: An SSL error may be a transient network problem - have you retried, perhaps check your local network and firewall settings? Can you reach https://files.pythonhosted.org in a browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate